# Composite Keys Rails Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, composite-primary-key

Going straight to the problem, I'm facing some problems with Active Record(**NO RAILS**) using composite keys. I'm using "gem composite_primary_keys" by the way. This table is a join table with two more fields. 
The problem is, when I do a simple query:

```
Freezer_Beer.find([freezer.id,beer.id]).take
```

It throws:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column freezer_beers.[:freezer_id, :beer_id] does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
SELECT  "freezer_beers".* FROM "freezer_beers"  WHERE "freezer_beers"."[:freezer_id, :beer_id]"
```

My models are:

```
class Freezer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :beers, :through => :freezer_beer
end

class Beer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :freezers, :through => :freezers_beers   
end

class Freezer_Beer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :freezer
  belongs_to :beer

  self.primary_key = :freezer_id, :beer_id
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `self.primary_keys = :freezer_id, :beer_id`, you have missed off an s.

Comment: Yes! Just one single 's' was killing it all! :(
The other problem was because I was not including it: require 'composite_primary_keys'